# Stored procedure for combining multiple queries output

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have 4 database tables,

```
session :
------------------------------------------------------
| userid  | session_id   |  sess_type  |  sess_time  |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 365672e3ab75 |  type-1     |  1463214751 |
| 2       | 2612fedcf78d |  type-2     |  1479111234 |
------------------------------------------------------

user :
----------------------------------
| userid  | name   |  user_type  |
----------------------------------
| 1       | Name-1 |  teacher    |
| 2       | Name-2 |  student    |
----------------------------------

teacher :
---------------------------------------------
| userid  | details-col1   |  details-col2  |
---------------------------------------------
| 1       | Value-1        |  Value-1       |
| 2       | Value-2        |  Value-2       |
---------------------------------------------

student :
---------------------------------------------
| userid  | student-col1   |  student-col2  |
---------------------------------------------
| 1       | Value-1        |  Value-1       |
| 2       | Value-2        |  Value-2       |
---------------------------------------------
```

Now, my requirement is :

1. I want a row from **"session"** table which matches **"session_id"** field with the session_id value provided in stored procedure parameter.
2. Also, I want a row in **"user"** table which matches its **"userid"** column value with the userid value from session table query output (specified above in point : 1).
3. Now, based on the value stored in **"user_type"** column in **"user"** table query output, query should be fired on corresponding database table.

   For e.g. If the value in **"user_type"** column is **"teacher"**, then query **"teacher"** table. Same for the value **"student"**.

I can accomplish above requirement in 3 different queries by providing one query's output in second query.
but, i want to accomplish it in one query/Stored-procedure only.

Please consider that Each of the database tables **"user"**, **"teacher"**, **"student"** may contain more than 1,000,000 rows in it. And both the tables **"teacher"** and **"student"** have more than 8 unique columns and may vary over the time.

What would be the most optmized stored Procedure to achieve this requirement?

```
Expected Output :

For Teacher :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| userid  | session_id   |  sess_type  |  sess_time  | name   |  user_type  | details-col1   |  details-col2  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 365672e3ab75 |  type-1     |  1463214751 | Name-1 |  teacher    | Value-1        |  Value-1       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For Student : 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| userid  | session_id   |  sess_type  |  sess_time  | name   |  user_type  | student-col1   |  student-col2  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 365672e3ab75 |  type-1     |  1463214751 | Name-1 |  teacher    | Value-1        |  Value-1       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you show the expected results for both users in your example?

Comment: I have added my expected output in the question... Please check..

Comment: So your result is dependent on user type and my return different column names, different data types and different number of columns?

Comment: Yes. Thats right

Comment: Then you'd need to construct the query dynamically in the SP. I wouldn't do that. That would make the code too complex without a good reason. I would run two queries. First two tables can be joined easily. Then run the second query depending on user type. Note that you usually only need to do that once per session (when the user logs in).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select different columns, you can do this in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT u.user_type, se.session_id, se.sess_type, se.sess_time, u.userid, u.name, u.user_type 
    INTO @user_type, @session_id, @sess_type, @sess_time, @userid, @name, @type
FROM user AS u
JOIN session AS se ON se.userid = u.userid
WHERE se.session_id = @session_id_param;

IF @user_type = 'student'
THEN
    SELECT @userid AS userid, @session_id AS session_id, @sess_type AS sess_type, @sess_time AS sess_time, @name AS name, @type AS user_type, s.student_col1, s.student_col2
    FROM student AS s
    WHERE s.userid = @userid
ELSE
    SELECT @userid AS userid, @session_id AS session_id, @sess_type AS sess_type, @sess_time AS sess_time, , @name AS name, @type AS user_type, t.details_col1, t.details_col2
    FROM teacher AS t
    WHERE t.userid = @userid
END IF;
```

Comment: Will it be the most optimized solution? is it faster than executing 3 different queries from PHP?

Comment: You cant use a union like that.. tables have different columns

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've changed it to list explicit columns, so he can choose the similar columns from each table.

Comment: @Vin A general rule is to minimize the number of queries, and do as much as you can in the database. This should be pretty efficient, because it may be able to tell quickly which of the two subqueries in the UNION it actually needs to execute, based on the user type.

Comment: Using fixed list of columns will introduce a dependency. Each time I add a column i have to update this query too.

Comment: How else can you use the same procedure with different tables? How would you know which columns it's going to return, since you don't know which table it will select from?

Comment: Maybe you should reorganize your tables. For all the things that students and teachers have in common, you should put them in one table. Then use separate `student` and `teacher` tables for the unique attributes. This procedure should only need to use the table with the common attributes.

Comment: for common columns, i have used the table "user".. And for unique columns, i am using different tables "teacher" and "student"

Comment: You could do it with two queries in the stored procedure. Do a first query that gets the user type, then use `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF` to do different queries for the different types.

Comment: First query is to get session_id from "session" table... Second query to get user_type from "user" table.... third query is to get all information based on userid in the table **[user_type]** which was obtained in second query

Comment: I can even join first two queries on my own... because of the Lack of knowledge about Mysql Parameters ;)

Comment: You can see that join as part of my query.

Comment: ok. so you mean.. it cant be optimized further? Firing 2 queries is the most efficient solution here?

Comment: I think the second part is a good solution for a bad requirement.

Comment: I've come up with a better version that doesn't need to do the join in the second query. It gets all the columns from the column tables into procedure variables, then just gets the columns from `teacher` or `student` in the second query.

Comment: `DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE load_loggedin_user (IN session_id_var CHAR(60))
BEGIN
  SELECT *, @userid_var:=userid FROM session WHERE session_id = session_id_var;

  SELECT *, @user_type_var:=user_type FROM user WHERE userid = @userid_var;

  IF (@user_type_var = 'teacher') THEN

    SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE userid = @userid_var;
  
  ELSEIF (@user_type_var = 'student') THEN

    SELECT * FROM student WHERE userid = @userid_var;

  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: above procedure gives me everything but in different rows... how can i join them?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very experienced with stored procedures, I got some of this wrong.

Comment: You need to use `SELECT ... INTO` so it doesn't return the first query from the procedure, it just assigns the variables. `SELECT @var := column` won't work for that.